# FCM (FirebaseMessagingService) : how to access FirebaseService to register the app for push notifications

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a xamarin.forms app that needs to use push notifications. I implemented it using this tutorial and sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#add-apns-notifications-to-xamarinforms-ui. I understand how this is done at installation time. But my app is assigned a group (subscription tag) only upon sign in, which happens after the installation. So at installation time the sign in information is not available. For Android, how can I access current FirebaseService object to call SendRegistrationToServer()?

I tried to call the following method after signing in:

```
    public void RegisterForGroup()
    {
        if (Preferences.ContainsKey(AppConstants.NotificationTokenKey))
        {
            string token = Preferences.Get(AppConstants.NotificationTokenKey, "");

            FirebaseService firebaseService = new FirebaseService();
            try
            {
                firebaseService.SendRegistrationToServer(token);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

But the following line within SendRegistrationToServer()

```
    NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub(AppConstants.NotificationHubName, AppConstants.ListenConnectionString, this);
```

gives an exception:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context
> android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object
> reference

That is why I think I need to use the original FirebaseService object rather than create new one. But how can I access the FirebaseService object?

Comment: Could you include some code to show what it is you have tried already?

Comment: @markbarton I added the code to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you needing to send the registration to the server at install time? Wouldn't it be better if it was done when the user has Opened the app? or possible when the first login?

Comment: @mark barton I do not need it at installation time. That is why I asked this question. I need to be able to register at any time, specifically after login. It is done at installation time by default, when OnNewToken() is called by the firebase framework.

Comment: @DavidShochet Hi, you could have a try with [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call that method created from the 
new created dependent class, not call it directly from `FirebaseService` class.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Yes, this works. I tried it before, but needed to pass FirebaseService object to NotificationHub constructor. I figured out I could use Application.Context from which FirebaseService inherits. Please make your suggestion the Answer, and I will mark it as such. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidShochet Great! Glad slved that. I have updated the answer. You also can share your solution in another answer. It will be helpful for others who have the same problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

From the error and shared code as follows:

```
 ...
 FirebaseService firebaseService = new FirebaseService();
 try
 {
    firebaseService.SendRegistrationToServer(token);
 }
 ...
```

It seems when calling `SendRegistrationToServer` method, the instance of `NotificationHub` or `Registration` can not be generated successfully.

Therefore, I will suggest that using [dependency service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to call that method created from the new created dependent class, not call it directly from `FirebaseService` class.